# TTS init lag after onInit()

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm writing an application which uses `GoogleTextToSpeech` for **French** language, the problem is that after `onInit` when I use `setLanguage` to change the tts language to **French** the tts object won't work for like 10-15 seconds. I have tried other languages (English, Deutsch) and there is no such problem. I wanna know if there is anyway to know that the tts object has actually started  for the selected language (after `onInit`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Just found a solution to this problem hope it helps others as well.
There is a method `setOnUtteranceProgressListener(UtteranceProgressListener)` which takes a listener and calls it for different events of TTS. so if you register your listener here, and also assign an utteranceId when calling `speak` method ([See how to assign UtteranceId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)). `OnStart` method gets called when the tts has actually started to speak. so you can show a progress or whatever from the time you call `speak` method until when `onStart` has not been called.